# macOS Sierra: Command-Tab window switching with fullscreen apps on multiple displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I use dual displays, and I like using apps in full screen mode.

For simplicity's sake let's pretend I'm using two applications, Google Chrome and Spotify.

The scenario is as follows:

Currently foregrounded application: **Spotify**

#### Monitor A

- Chrome (non-fullscreen)

#### Monitor B

- Chrome (non-fullscreen)
- Spotify (fullscreen)

Then ⌘+Tab over to Chrome.

*Desired outcome*: Both displays switch to the two different Chrome windows.

*Actual outcome*: Basically nothing. Spotify stays fullscreen, because there is another Chrome window available that it switches to (on Monitor A).

Note that this is distinct from the case if none of the apps are fullscreen, in which case all Chrome windows would foreground.

It is also distinct from the case when the only available Chrome window shares the display with the fullscreen app. In that case that display will change desktops.

I hope this question isn't too convoluted, but I did my best to describe the scenario precisely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm... yeah, it's pretty convoluted ;)
but I think you could fix this by not treating each Display as its own Space.

I don't think you can have exactly what you want in all scenarios - e.g. this will move the menu bar & Dock to only the primary Display, and/but will make the Displays move in pairs, rather than independently.

**System Prefs > Mission Control >** *uncheck* **Displays have separate Spaces**

You cannot bypass the issue that a fullscreen Space cannot be assigned a number & therefore cannot be assigned a hot-key. It will always be *number of Spaces + one to the right*

Caveat: you also need to uncheck 'Automatically rearrange Spaces...' to retain full control over the numbering/hot-keying.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, this was a good try but it doesn't do what I want. It actually makes matters worse, because when I go fullscreen in this mode, it just makes the other display go blank. If it was just the loss of separate menu bars we were talking about I think I could live with that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You did give me the idea that is the next best thing though! Which is to use the `Ctrl-1`, `Ctrl-2` method for switching between desktops. As long as I can do this to return to my non-fullscreen desktops, that gives me the speed and flexibility I wanted out of the `Alt-Tab` approach. Thanks!

Comment: tbh, I use the hot-keys entirely to do this, across 7 Spaces & 2 screens, & avoid fullscreen altogether [I just Maximise instead] - because whoever invented fullscreen forgot about how Spaces works. [Spaces actually was better before Mission Control came along]

Comment: yeah I totally see how that can work. Maybe its a weird nervous tick but I just find that little extra strip of window at the top annoying and distracting in certain applications, for instance my text editor. Hence fullscreen. And with a combo of these hotkeys and triple-finger swipe on my MBP and "Reduce Motion" enabled, it is actually speedy and nice to switch between things now. Thanks again for the tips

Comment: I've been used to that little strip for 25 years or so... I just don't notice it. BTW, ctrl+number is faster than ctrl+left//right [which is what the gesture does] at default settings.